# Окончание поддержки node js

Tags: node.js

Всем доброго времени суток.

Я новичок в JS, собираюсь изучать Node.js.

Увидел на официальном сайте [заметку](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/nodejs16-eol/), что поддержка node js завершается к сентябрю 2023 года. Как быть?

Это получается, что апдейты выходить не будут и придется использовать альтернативу Node Js вот уже через год? Есть ли смысл учить эту технологию, учитывая эту не очень уж и "приятную" новость?

Comment: "Node.js 16" уже 18я версия)

Comment: Завершается поддержка только 16-ой версии Node.js; помимо них есть ещё здравствующие 17-ая и 18-ая версия, так что Node.js уж точно в ближайшее время не загнётся :)

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле уйдёт лишь **одна из текущих активных версий LTS** `Node.js`: в неподдерживаемый режим, или `End-of-life`, `Node.js 16.x` уйдёт из-за окончания поддержки связанного с ним `OpenSSL 1.1.1`. Последний же должен перестать поддерживаться, опять же, к сентябрю 2023 года, поэтому разработчики решили вместе с ним досрочно завершить поддержку и `Node.js 16.x`.

И да, помимо `Node.js 16.x`, есть ещё более новые версии: `Node.js 17.x`, который будет служить до 1 июня 2023 года, а также `Node.js 18.x` — до 30 апреля 2026 года. Отсюда следует, что одна из этих версий попросту заменит `Node 16.x` как основную.

TL;DR: это не финальная версия ноды, а всего лишь одна из многих, а после неё уже есть две версии, 17-ая и 18-ая. Смысл учить, конечно же, был, есть и остаётся ^.^